# Are these arrows indicating the spin of electrons?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

What are those horizontal and vertical arrows indicates?

[image]

Image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijosf90RAG8 at 02:30

Comment: I assume this is a magnet being dropped through a conducting pipe?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes

Answer (score 0):

No, those are not electron spins! In fact, the video has indicated what they are! The green arrows are eddy currents, while the orange/yellow arrows are the 'secondary' magnetic field produced by these eddy currents.

[Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) states that the direction of current induced by a changing magnetic field is in the direction such that it produces a magnetic field that opposes that change. In this case, the moving magnet (and thus changing magnetic field at different points on the conductive tube) produces an induced current (which is termed eddy current in the video). As the current carrying wire produces a magnetic field, this induced current produces a current as well, which opposes the change in the original magnetic field.

I think this youtube video has step by step video on what the arrows mean: [magnetic braking](https://youtu.be/otu-KV3iH_I?t=1m10s)